# Using Select function based on data range

Tags: list-manipulation

I am using Select to take values from a multidimensional list based on a previously calculated range.

The list is of time and position of a particle over time steps done for multiple particles. The structure of the list `meansqdCut` is

```
meansqdCut = {{{t10,x10},{t11,x11}},{{t20,x20}{t21,x21}},..,{{tn0,xn0},{tn1,xn1}}}
```

Where t10 is first particle, 0th time step. So for example (2 time steps)

```
meansqdCut = {{{0,0},{1,5}},{{0,0},{1,8}},...,{{0,0},{1,6}}}
```

I have previously plotted the data and I'm using the first maximum of position as the upper limit of the range. Using

```
peaks = FindPeaks[meansqdCut[[#, All, 2]]] & /@ Range [1, upper]
```

finds the position of the maxima and I'm using the first maximum to specify the higher extent of the range. 
I want to take all elements of the list for each particle up to a point where the x value is greater than the maximum specified by `peaks`.Then using the select function:

```
meansqdCutMax = 
  Select[meansqdCut[[#]], 0 <= #[[1]] <= peaks[[#, 1, 1]] &] & /@ 
   Range [1, 10]
```

Where `Range[1,10]` means performing this operation on particles 1 to 10. Each particle will have a different range of elements I want to select.

This gives me multiple errors saying that `"The expression {0.943462,0.} cannot be used as a part specification"` and I'm not sure why this arises.

If I replace the upper limit of the range with a number so

```
meansqdCutMax = 
      Select[meansqdCut[[#]], 0 <= #[[1]] <= 100 &] & /@ 
       Range [1, 10]
```

then I get the desired output. So I'm presuming it is a problem with the `#` in the upper limit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `upper`? Is it `Length@meansqdCut`? What is the structure of `meansqdCut`? Is it `{ {pos of particle 1 at time t0, pos of particle 2 at time t0}, {pos of particle 1 at time t1, pos of particle 2 at time t1}, ...}`? Are you using `FindPeaks` to find which of the second elements is greater? What are you `Select`ing for? Point is: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, sorry, it is a bit unclear, I'll edit my question and make it clearer.

Comment: I have removed the 'upper' and changed it to 10. This specifies which particles I want to perform this operation on.

Comment: I'm guessing that in `peaks[[#, 1, 1]]`, the `#` is supposed to be the `Slot` for the outer function that is being `Map`ped over `Range[1, 10]`, but since it is insede the test function for `Select`, you are feeding elements of `meansqdCut[[#]]` to it. How about this instead: `Cases[meansqdCut[[#]], a_ /; 0 <= a[[1]] <= peaks[[#, 1]]] & /@ Range[1, 10]`

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to add a more complicated example of `meansqdCut`, one where `meansqdCutMax` actually produces something different than just the original list, because we might be able to come up with something a little cleaner.

Comment: 'meansqdCut = {{{167.936, 30.5886}, {169.068, 30.6858}, {170.012, 30.7153}, {170.955, 30.6754}, {172.087, 30.5535}},{{137.934, 14.6745}, {139.066, 14.7409}, {140.01, 14.7693}, {140.953,14.7645}, {142.085, 14.738}}}'   For 2 particles over a range where both have maxima. Trying to put this in 'code' format! thanks for your help

Comment: The `Cases` function worked! I'll add an answer of the final code I used!

Comment: I still don't quite get it, but okay!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working using one of the suggestions by `@march`

> I'm guessing that in `peaks[[#, 1, 1]]`, the `#` is supposed to be the `Slot` for the outer function that is being `Map`ped over `Range[1, 10]`, but since it is insede [*sic*] the test function for `Select`, you are feeding elements of `meansqdCut[[#]]` to it. How about this instead: `Cases[meansqdCut[[#]], a_ /; 0 <= a[[1]] <= peaks[[#, 1]]] & /@ Range[1, 10]` – `march`

My final line of code was:

```
meansqdCutMax = Cases[meansqdCut[[#]], a_ /; 0 <= a[[1]] <= peaks[[#, 1, 1]]] & /@ Range[1, upper];
```

Which solved the problem with the use of `Slot`s for the `Select` and the `Map`ping.

I'm sorry for my lack of clarity on this question, I'm very new to Mathematica (as you can all probably tell)! Thank you very much for your help @march